# Where does Server.app log upgrade errors?

Tags: macos, server.app

I recently ran updates from the Mac App Store for Server app and once the download finishes, I got the typical services are stopped message since a new server is present in /Applications.

After starting the app and proceeding to upgrade the services, I received a vague error message:

[image: Server upgrade error message]

Everything seems to be functional, all services that should run are green and I see that the System is at OS X 10.8.5 (Build 12F45) and Server 2.2.2 (Build 12T214) as expected.

Where do the Service Data errors or status get logged so I can check what errors occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to find more information regarding OS X Server migration and upgrade errors in the file:`/Library/Logs/ServerSetup.log`

Comment: This file was last updated at the same time as the migration and seems to contain some errors different than most of my servers that upgraded to 10.8.5